# <button type="button" - pass value through POST to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I should have tried to write some more details erlier. 
I need a kind of questionnaire with questions with only one of several answers you can choose.
The questionnare is grouped into `<fieldset>`elements which are made visible after the last groups question answered. 
Due to design reasons, I have a written the with several `button` elements which are set to type "button".
I cannot let the page reload inbetween answering the questionnaire.

Now I want to pass their value, if clicked to PHP to save them to a database.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      var current = 1,
        current_step, next_step, steps;
      var buttonname = '';
      var buttonvalue = '';
      var btnarray = [];
      steps = $(".fieldset").length;
      $(".next").click(function() {
        buttonname = $(this).attr('name');
        buttonvalue = $(this).val();
        btnarray.push(buttonname + ":" + buttonvalue);
        current_step = $(this).parents("fieldset");
        next_step = $("fieldset").eq(current);
        buttonvalue = $(this).val();
        current_step.hide();
        next_step.show();
        //setProgressBar(++current);




      });
      
      });
```

```css
.parallelogram {
  background: #fff;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  position: relative;
  border: solid 5px #0793EB;
  margin-left: -10px;
  transform: skew(-15deg);
  font-size: 24pt;
  color: #0793EB;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="reg_form" novalidate action="action.php" method="POST">
  <fieldset>
  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="topic[]" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 1-1</span></button>

  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="topic[]" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 1-2</span></button>
 </fieldset>
 
   <fieldset hidden>
  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="secondtopic[]" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 2-1</span></button>

  <button type="button" class="parallelogram next" name="secondtopic[]" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 2-2</span></button>
 </fieldset>
 </form>
```

In Firebug, I can see the parameters and also the array in the preview, but `var_dump($_POST);` does not give me anything.

Does anybody has an idea?

Thanks in advance.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

give buttons as array and you can access that in php.

```
  <button type="submit" class="parallelogram next" name="topic[]" value="1"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 1</span></button>

      <button type="submit" class="parallelogram next" name="topic[]" value="2"><span class="text-uppercase boldtext">Button 2</span></button>



   <?php

       $buttonData = $_POST['topic'];

  // do database operations
    ?>
```

Comment: The thing is, that it is a multi-step form, and I only want to submit at the end. So I defined the buttons as type="button" to stay on my page.